# Given unix time and timezone name, determine if DST is in effect

Tags: php, timezone, dst

What it says.  Language is PHP (in a Moodle farmework).  Timestamp may be in future or past.  Timezone name is a standard US timezone name (I can survive if it doesn't work outside the USA), could use UTC instead (again, doesn't need to work outside USA) or some such.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155224/php-daylight-saving-time-detection
that should get you started

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [PHP Date + Time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)