# DateTimeZone and UTC offset for Standard and Daylight Times

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

I have a problem to get UTC offset information out of PHP DateTimeZone and the underlying database. I'm get close for every DT/ST pair, but the time-zone with commonly one hour less (DT) isn't.

For example ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone)):

**Eastern Daylight Time** (**EDT**), when observing daylight saving time (spring/summer) is 4 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (**UTC−04:00**).

**Eastern Standard Time** (**EST**) when observing standard time (autumn/winter) are 5 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (**UTC−05:00**).

So far I obtain the UTC offset (in `DateTimeZone::getOffset` it's said against GMT but I assume this is the same) as in the following code:

```
$zones = ['EDT', 'EST'];

foreach ($zones as $zone) {
    // get offset
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone($zone);
    $offset = $timezone->getOffset(new DateTime(null, $timezone));

    printf("%s (%s) %s\n", $zone, $timezone->getName(), format_offset($offset));
}
```

Exemplary output ([full example](http://3v4l.org/XuhI6), I use PHP 5.6.1RC1):

```
EDT (EDT) -0500
EST (EST) -0500
```

These two timezones are actually exemplary, I'd like to do that with others as well, however I don't want to hardcode the offsets but instead want to figure this out with PHP's **DateTimeZone**.

I might run into a bug here when I see the [output across multiple PHP versions](http://3v4l.org/XuhI6), looks like that HHVM does not have this issue by transposing it:

```
Output for hhvm-3.2.0 - 3.3.0

EDT (America/New_York) -0400
EST (EST) -0500

Output for 5.5.10 - 5.6.2, php7@20140507 - 20141001

EDT (EDT) -0500
EST (EST) -0500

Output for 5.2.0 - 5.5.9

EDT (America/New_York) -0400
EST (America/New_York) -0400
```

Is there a cross-PHP version compatible way? Not fiddling that deep with `DateTimeZone` normally and so far I had the impression it would work well.

Comment: Not sure is this will help but it is possible to find out is DST is being applied : [6155224/php-daylight-saving-time-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155224/php-daylight-saving-time-detection)

Comment: @RyanVincent: Yes, I think it's related. The problem seems to be that EST and EDT are not timezones in the timezone database PHP uses. They also don't throw an exception, so in the end I will need to keep a list of those anyways.

Answer (score 6):

PHP uses the standard [IANA tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  You can find a list of supported time zones either [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), or [in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

In particular, you will find that values like `"EST"` are there for backwards compatibility only.  You can see that in [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) of the docs, there is a large red warning about *not* using time zones of that format.  And while `"EST"` is in the list of deprecated zones, `"EDT"` is not.

In general, time zone abbreviations make poor identifiers because there are too many ambiguities.  Consider [this list of abbreviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), which has two different interpretations of EDT, 5 different interpretations of CST, and many other conflicts.

Also consider that a full identifier like `"America/New_York"` is accurately representing both EST and EDT, and has all of the knowledge of when to transition between them - including historical differences.

In the code you provided, you are asking PHP for the *current* offset for EST and EDT separately.  That doesn't make sense, since EDT is only in effect for part of the year, and EST and EDT can't be in effect at the same time in the same location.  Instead, use the `"America/New_York"` offset, and provide a specific time to get the offset at that time.

If you just want the standard and daylight offsets for each zone, you can test midnight on January 1st and July 1st of the current year.  Whichever is lower is the standard offset.  If they are the same, then (usually) the time zone doesn't use DST.

Comment: I also tried with other dates, like `2014-01-01` and `2014-06-30` - it didn't made any difference, also not for EDT. I assume that **DateTimeZone** UTC offset gives for standard and not daylight saving time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `"EDT"` by itself is not a valid input to use with `DateTimeZone`.  It's not in [the list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) anyway.

Comment: So what it really comes own to is where do you get the list of time zones in your real application?  If you call [`DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php), the only way to get the backwards compatible zones is to explicitly ask for them by passing the [`DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php#datetimezone.constants.all-with-bc) parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Not all time-zone which PHP's [**DateTimeZone**](http://php.net/datetimezone) accepts as string in the ctor's `$timezone` parameter does actually have a stable UTC-offset. Technically speaking, those two **EDT** and **EST**, aren't real time-zones, the time-zone is **Eastern Time Zone** (**ET**) which is **US/Eastern** or **America/New_York** in the [*tz database*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and that is the datasource PHP's **DateTimeZone** operates on.

```
+------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| string           | getName()          | offsets                                 |
+------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| America/New_York | (America/New_York) | -0500 / -0400 (2012-01-01 / 2012-06-30) |
| US/Eastern       | (US/Eastern)       | -0500 / -0400 (2012-01-01 / 2012-06-30) |
| EDT              | (EDT)              | -0500 / -0500 (2012-01-01 / 2012-06-30) |
| EST              | (EST)              | -0500 / -0500 (2012-01-01 / 2012-06-30) |
+------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

So especially those two **EDT** and **EST** in my question do not work well because they represent standard and daylight saving time separated, while PHP's **DateTimeZone** does represent both. Therefore the UTC offset is ambiguous. The [PHP manual documents](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) that those are accepted for backward-compatibility reasons only and they should not be used with the **DateTimeZone** class. A user-note on the page says it well:

> Don’t use 'EST', at least in PHP 5.3.3 it’s the same as 'EST5EDT' rather than being strictly standard time. The only reliable way I’ve found to interpret a time as standard time is to use a UTC-relative format such as:
>
> ```
> $dateObject = date_create("2013-06-30 07:00:00-0500");
> ```

This is sort of also what the specification I work with (*4.3. Obsolete Date and Time*; [RFC2822 p. 32](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-32)) is saying, that using those zones is obsolete. I just hoped I could have spared me the creation of a time-zone to UTC-offset map:

```
EDT is semantically equivalent to -0400
EST is semantically equivalent to -0500
CDT is semantically equivalent to -0500
CST is semantically equivalent to -0600
MDT is semantically equivalent to -0600
MST is semantically equivalent to -0700
PDT is semantically equivalent to -0700
PST is semantically equivalent to -0800
```

But it's not such a large list.

Comment: That small handful of abbreviations works if you are only considering North America.  As soon as you start to consider the world at large, [it all falls apart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).  If you can guarantee that you are parsing an RFC822/1123/2822 timestamp, you can use those (and only those) abbreviations.  But most of the time, you should not count on that.

Comment: Yes, normally only those. Part of the question why I ask is as RFC2822 suggests to accept other values as well if off-band-information is reliable. Had the idea to make use of PHP's **DateTimeZone** for that however it turned out it's not doing generally well with that (the parser can actually just accept anything which could be a TZ, as RFC2822 names the common 3-5 alphas, so at good luck passing it in there but that's not an option esp. not for those eight). So I dropped it.

Comment: Keep in mind that the RFC822/1123/2822 and related formats are quite old.  They're still in use by a lot of things like HTTP and email, but most modern systems use ISO8601, and typically the profile described in RFC3339.  Unless you absolutely have to use it for some reason, you shouldn't.

Comment: RFC3339 (2002) relates to a decent extend to RFC2822 (2001) and has good discussion material on RFC822, esp. why those zones do not play well. Thanks for the hint. For that profile I've got another parser in the pipe as PHP has problems to parse those timestamps, too.