# PHP DateTime returning negative hours value

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to work around problem with php DateTime witch returns me weird values in some specific cases.

For example, my code:

```
$start = new \DateTime("2018-10-04 00:00");
$end = new \DateTime("2018-10-28 23:59");
$diff = $end->diff($start);
```

returns:

```
DateInterval {#2311 ▼
  +"y": 0
  +"m": 0
  +"d": 25
  +"h": -1
  +"i": 59
  +"s": 59
  +"f": 0.0
  +"weekday": 0
  +"weekday_behavior": 0
  +"first_last_day_of": 0
  +"invert": 1
  +"days": 24
  +"special_type": 0
  +"special_amount": 0
  +"have_weekday_relative": 0
  +"have_special_relative": 0
}
```

"25 days **-1 hour** 59 minutes".

Function works perfect in most cases. This happens only sometimes, but still being a problem... Is there any way to get normal format of days/hours without recalculating this weird values every time?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with PHP 5.5 or higher: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/afa3f877915105caba8ef6af66c830f9d46a8c27

Comment: I presume it happens when you cross time zone boundaries due to daylight saving time. It's a situation that PHP doesn't handle as well as it should. In practice I've found that these kind of calculations work better when switching everything to UTC.

Comment: I am totally agree with @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: @RobbieAverill Try with a time zone within the European Union, e.g. `Europe/Amsterdam'.

Comment: Thanks! It was probably a problem with a timezone and a CEST/CET shift in October.

Comment: https://joshtronic.com/2013/11/04/handle-daylight-savings-time/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155224/php-daylight-saving-time-detection

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alvaro i found the solution:

```
$start = new \DateTime("2018-10-04 00:00", new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$end = new \DateTime("2018-10-28 23:59", new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$diff = $end->diff($start);
```

The problem was probably my Europe/Warsaw timezone and CEST/CET timeshift during above period.

Comment: Please note this doesn't render totally correct results if the dates are meant to be in local time. In such case you'd need to create instances in local time and then [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) to UTC.

Comment: Works with all my dataset, but You are probably right. You can always change TimeZone if You need it.