# Timezone Conversion is giving one hour more in PHP

Tags: php, timezone

I have this following script:

```
$data = array(
  'fromTimezone'          => 'Asia/Kolkata',
  'toTimezone'            => 'America/New_York',
  'dateTime'              => '2020-02-06 08:34:11',
  'dateTimeFormat'        => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
);

$fromTimezone           = $data['fromTimezone'];
$toTimezone             = $data['toTimezone'];
$dateTime               = $data['dateTime'];
$dateTimeFormat         = $data['dateTimeFormat'];


$fromZoneDateTime    = new DateTime($dateTime, new DateTimeZone($fromTimezone));

// synchronizing with the to-Timezone
$fromZoneDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($toTimezone));

$returnDateTime    = date($dateTimeFormat, strtotime($fromZoneDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
echo $returnDateTime;
```

This is giving me `2020-02-05 22:04:11`

But when I am checking the time in Real Time Application for Timezone conversion. like [The Time Zone Converter](https://www.thetimezoneconverter.com/), I am getting data as `2020-02-05 23:04:11`.

[image]

Why is this mismatch? How can I overcome this?

Comment: The online is today not 02-05.

Comment: @AbraCadaver. Can you explain?

Comment: Daylight savings time in the US added 1 hour starting 03-08 so there is an added hour between your check of 02-05 and today 04-21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you referenced is showing you the difference between your local time zone (presumably India) and the time in New York *for the current date*.

There are other sites that you can use to validate your assumptions, such as timeanddate.com, [which shows the correct results for the date in question](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20200206T030400&p1=54&p2=179), which align to your code output.

[image: screenshot]

As for *why*, understand that while India is fixed to UTC+05:30 (IST), New York alternates between UTC-05:00 (EST) and UTC-04:00 (EDT).  For more on this, please read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section "Time Zone != Offset".  You might also want to review [the DST tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because of the day light savings.

Please refer [PHP daylight saving time detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155224/php-daylight-saving-time-detection)

Comment: How to overcome this?

Comment: The time is the time what do you want to overcome?

Comment: @Saswat - There's nothing to overcome.  As AbraCadaver points out - the time conversion is correct.